# "Timed out while waiting for the program to exit" - CS50 FIGlet

Tags: python, cs50, figlet

I just finished week 6 lecture and I'm doing the practice problems. I'm stuck with FIGlet, I don't understand why I get the timeout error message with check50 :/

[check50 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjnu.png)

```
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from sys import argv
import sys
import random

figlet = Figlet()

string = input("Input: ")

# the user would like to output text in a random font.
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    figlet.setFont(font=random.choice(font_list))
    print(f"Output: {figlet.renderText(string)}")

# the user would like to output text in a specific font
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and (argv[1] == "-f" or argv[1] == "--font"):

    if argv[2] in figlet.getFonts():
        figlet.setFont(font=argv[2])
        print(f"Output: {figlet.renderText(string)}")
    else:
        sys.exit("Invalid usage")

# otherwise error
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid usage")
```

the program works as intended when I do the tests..
Can you please help me out?
It's only my second attempt at python so if you also have tips on how to make the code better I would appreciate it!

Comment: You need to explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: You shouldn't ask for the string to print when the command-line arguments are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for input when the arguments are invalid. Check the arguments first, then ask for input and print the result at the end.

```
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from sys import argv
import sys
import random

figlet = Figlet()

# the user would like to output text in a random font.
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    figlet.setFont(font=random.choice(font_list))

# the user would like to output text in a specific font
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and (argv[1] == "-f" or argv[1] == "--font"):
    if argv[2] in figlet.getFonts():
        figlet.setFont(font=argv[2])
    else:
        sys.exit("Invalid usage")

# otherwise error
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid usage")

string = input("Input: ")
print(f"Output: {figlet.renderText(string)}")
```

It's timing out because `check50` doesn't provide any input when it gives invalid arguments, so the script is waiting forever for that.